# MySQL multilingual table structure

Tags: mysql, localization, database-schema, multilingual

I have a website with 2 items that need to be translated in different languages: articles and products.

For the articles I created two tables:

```
[articles]
  id PK
  posted_on

[articles_local]
  id PK
  article_id FK(articles.id)
  title
  body
  lang_code
```

I could have created three tables to also store the language code and id but I thought it was overkill because my application is relatively small.

The problem is with the products. The products have two information that need to be translated, the product name and the product category; all the others are neutral and equal to all languages.

Here is my table structure for the products, which I need help with:

```
[products]
  id PK
  name // always the same in all languages
  product_code
  weight
  image_url
  category_id FK (category.id)

[category]
  id PK
  cat_name_IT
  cat_name_EN
  cat_nameRU

[products_local]
  id PK
  product_id FK(products.id)
  prod_description
  lang_code
```

So basically the `category` table holds the translated category names for the three languages. The categories are 6 in total and won't change any time soon.

The `products_local` only has the translated description of the product and the `product` table the information that is the same for each language.

I think that my products structure is a bit messed up but I can't figure why and also how can I improve. I think this based on the articles structure which to me seems more 'right' and clean.

Is there any way I can improve this table structure ?

I don't know if it matters, but in my `php` I extract the articles and products based on the folder name, `it`, `en`, `ru`:

```
$lang = // get folder name from URI
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles_local WHERE lang_code = :lang";
// bind $lang to :lang
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok I think.

If you only need the translations in two or three fixed languages, I would just add the translation fileds into the normal products table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I could do that but it feels more organized and manageable this way and if in the future I will need to change something or add more columns, this way is easier.